How to create a .csv file with semicolon separation in XLSX npm
I'm triying to create a csv file with XLSX package from npm, and the result is the values separated by , (colon) and i want to be by ; (semicolon). How can I do it?
LSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, fileName);
const options = { cellDates: true };
const file = XLSX.writeFile(workbook, `${fileNameWithLocation}${extension}`, options);


Documentation Link: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/api/utilities/csv/
Should be something like this
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const fs = require("fs");

const data = [
  ["Name", "Age", "Country"],
  ["Alice", 30, "Canada"],
  ["Bob", 25, "USA"],
  ["Charles, Jr.", 35, "UK"],
];

const worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
let csv = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet, { FS: ";" });

fs.writeFileSync("output.csv", csv);

